# Java Conditional making it simple

Tags: java, conditional-statements

I need to condense two if else into one statement. 
Code is perfectly fine however it can not have two if-else. Both codes have same problem.

```
public boolean isClear(int index) {
    if (index < 32) {
        if ((bits & 0x00000001 << index) == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    } else
        return true;
}

public boolean isSet(int index) {
    if (index < 32) {
        if ((bits & 0x00000001 << index) != 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: How about using `&&`

Comment: And? You don't want to do that yourself or what is the question/confusion here?

Comment: I dont know how to do it.

Comment: @BabyC0d3eR: Step 1: Write unit tests which validate all logical cases for these methods.  Step 2: Modify this code to produce the same logic but be shorter for some reason.  Step 3: Validate the changes by running the tests.

Answer (score 2):

Shorter:

```
public boolean isClear(int index)
{
    return (index < 32) ? (bits & 0x00000001<<index) == 0 : true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is only one path in `isSet` that returns `true`, so `return` it. Like,

```
public boolean isSet(int index) {
    return (index < 32) && ((bits & 0x00000001 << index) != 0);
}
```

And then `isClear` can be the negation of that.

```
public boolean isClear(int index)
{
    return !isSet(index);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick Response. It worked like charm. Also Thanks @schwobaseggl for your input as well.